# Попавший(ся) под руку - обе формы существуют?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

Попавший под руку или попавшийся под руку?

> Учитель, не любящий процесс учительства вкупе с попавшимся под руку
> ученичеством, но исполняющий его мастерски, может быть весьма
> продуктивен, но...

Comment: Галина, непонятно, как здесь использовано слово "ученичество".  И к чему относится "исполняющий **его**".

Comment: Его - процесс; ученичество -  пребывание в состоянии ученика, но если не годится - исправлю. Как?

Comment: *Учитель, не любящий процесс учительства, но исполняющий его мастерски, может быть весьма продуктивен* -- вот это понятно. А с ученичеством почему-то у меня мозги нараскоряку...

Comment: Саш, я не знаю. Знаю, что синоним к ученику мне не нужен. Как в массе своей будут обозначаться ученики?

Comment: Искала-искала синоним сомнительному ученичеству, получилось: "Учитель, не любящий процесс учительства - вкупе с попавшейся под руку постылой паствой, - но исполняющий его мастерски, может быть весьма продуктивен, но..."

Comment: Галина, вообще, скорее всего "попавшийСЯ" правильно, как "подвернувшийся" - то есть возвратная форма. На нац корпусе только 2 варианта "попавший" и около 20 - попавшийся. Попавший можно перепутать с названием кого-то, кто "например" выстрелил "под руку". Стрелок попавший под руку выстрелом кому-то. А с попавшийся такого не провернёшь,  там всё однозначно.

Comment: Спасибо, берём! Ответом оформи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем размышления навели на то, что -СЯ сохраняет причинность и указывает на субъектность отношений, причём скорее всего для обеих сторон, в то время как отсутствие -СЯ лишает субъектности того, к кому или чему относится, делая его пассивным участником обстоятельств непреодолимой силы, и кроме того форма без -СЯ требует указания обстоятельств произошедшего, либо указание субъекта действия.

*Попавшие(**куда?**/**к кому?** - **к** охотнику) в яму звери* - звери не думали, не гадали, что станут целью чьего-то внешнего воздействия, хотя не ясно какого, или обстоятельств непреодолимой силы - но попали, - однако почему - не ясно. Кроме того, *попавшие* задает обстоятельственный контекст, попавшие куда(откуда) - в яму, а "попавшие звери" звучит недосказано.

*Попавшиеся(**кто?/кому?**) звери* - звери бегали по своим делам, а попасть к охотнику не хотели, избегали, но попались, и сразу понятно, что кто-то их ловил, появляется образ охотника, а звери становятся его добычей. Есть причина, а обстоятельства становятся вторичным делом, поэтому их можно опустить.

Кроме того, "попавшие звери" - куда или к кому? - не понятно, они субъектны или объектны? Потому что это звери которые попались куда-то, или звери которые попали туда, куда целились? То есть тут возникает двойственность прочтения.

Поэтому знаменитая подколка "ну ты попал!" сбивает с толку именно потому, что она не говорит, куда попал и в тоже время не говорит, почему "попал" - двойная ловушка для ума. А вот если бы говорили "ну ты попался!" - это бы значило сразу, я тебя ловил и поймал, и не вызывало бы такого замешательства.

Также не все формы можно превращать из обстоятельных в причинные и наоборот:

Камень упавший - упавшийся не говорят.

Камень скатившийся - скативший будет не тоже самое, и вообще не будет относится к камню, а будет относится к тому, кто его скатил.

На Нацкорпусе форма "попавший под руку" употреблена всего два раза, а попавшийся около 20 раз.

Comment: Метафора в ударении, конечно,  есть, мы камень под рУку не кладем. Но это ничего не решает. Попавший и попавшийся - это разная активность взаимодействия камня и человека. Такое впечатление, что камень НАМЕРЕННО попал нам под руку, такой он живой и активный. Вот в чем образность и фразеология. А если попался, то образность снижается. Значит, правильно: попал под руку.   А пользователи, как обычно, метафору не замечают и всё перестраивают под свое понимание. Так вы рекомендуете фразу:  с попавшимСЯ под руку ученичеством?

Comment: @Sharon он положил камень под рУку, чтобы опёреться (на камень). Попавший не имеет значения активного действия, так как это пассивное действие или случайное событие. "Попал пОд руку" - не понятно говорится о ловившем или попавшемся. А в случае с +СЯ такого разночтения не возникает. Я попал под руку ему ~ я попал в него/ он попал мне под руку ~ он мне попался - необходимо уточнение действия "попал".

Comment: Попавший не имеет значения активного действия? Очень даже имеет, всё по грамматике. Камень попал человеку под руку. Причастие обозначает действие камня. Метафора!   Камень попался человеку под руку. Причастие обозначает взаимодействие человека и камня. Нет метафоры. Ну нет так нет, обойдемся без нее.  Вот и все объяснение. Просто используем частотный вариант из Нацкорпуса.

Comment: https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/попавший+под+руку     https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/попавшийся+под+руку

Comment: @Sharon Попал+ся. Брошенный мною камень попался человеку в лицо - не скажешь, только попал. Брошенный камень попал человеку - куда? - тоже не скажешь. Без -ся требуется обстоятельность,  с -ся начинается конфликт с обстоятельностью из-за субъектности. Ввиду того, что "пОд руку" - это не обстоятельство, а образный оборот, то применимо только попался, попавшийся. А если это обстоятельство, то - "пад рУку" - попавший пад рУку камень.

Comment: @Sharon Я рассуждаю через логику вопрос-ответ и равнозначность употребления, как видите, слова не взаимозаменяемы, даже если не учитывать разницу в акценте ударения "под руку". Вопросы разные, слова существуют иначе. Чем руководствовались данные авторы и переводчики при выборе тех или иных вариантов, я не могу сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно:

*Учитель, не любящий процесс учительства **(вкупе с попавшимися под руку учениками),** но исполняющий его мастерски, может быть весьма продуктивен, но...*

**Пояснение**

1. Ученики тоже разные. Кто-то **попал** по желанию, а кто-то **попался**, потому что случайно оказался.
2. Не стоит **перегружать** предложение смысловыми оттенками разного рода, иначе оно перестает читаться и пониматься. Или нужно использовать вставки.
3. Фразу лучше полностью **перестроить** (повтор союза ***НО***). Также: **исполнять** его (процесс)? Повтор **однокоренных** слов.

"Ученичество" можно оставить (авт. неологизм по аналогии со студенчеством), но нужны **кавычки.**

4. **Вариант:** *Можно не любить сам процесс учительства, **вкупе с попавшимся под руку "ученичеством**," и все же работать мастерски.  Такой учитель продуктивен, но...*

**ПОПАСТЬСЯ**, -падусь, -падёшься; попался, -лась, -лось; попавшийся; св. 1. Оказаться **против воли,** случайно в каких-л. условиях, **обстоятельствах**. П. в капкан. П. на глаза кому-л. (=попасть на глаза). // Оказаться уличённым в чём-л. П. на краже, в краже.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152158/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.